# GPLv2 で、リンクを禁止する条文はどれ？

Tags: ライセンス, gpl

GPLv2 (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt) を見ていました。

その条文の、一番最後に、 (そして How to Apply These Terms to Your New Programs の中で)

> This General Public License does not permit incorporating your program
>   into proprietary programs.  If your program is a subroutine library,
>   you may consider it more useful to permit linking proprietary
>   applications with the library.  If this is what you want to do, use
>   the GNU Lesser General Public License instead of this License.

と記述がありました。

これは、 GPL をどのように新規作成プログラムに適用するかについてのべている章での話なので、条文の上の方(Terms and conditions)のどこかしらに、リンクを禁止する条文があったのではないかと思っているのですが、該当部分が見つけられずにいます。

質問:

- GPLv2 で、プロプライエタリソフトウェアからのリンクを禁止している条文は、どれですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GPL2では動的リンクについて明確に記載がありません。ただ、FSFは「メモリを共有してリンクされている場合には、それらは一つのプログラムと見なす」と解釈・主張しています。

このFSFの主張はそれなりに支持されていますが、確定したものでは無く、判例等も無いはずです。

Answer (score 2):

別段禁止がされているわけではなく、

リンクをした場合は同一のプログラムとみなしGPLを適用する
→ GPLと互換のないライセンスを採用するプログラムとリンクをするとライセンス上の矛盾が生じる
→ リンクを**避けたい**

だと思います。